# Add phone extension number to VCF contact file

Tags: android, contacts, vcf-vcard

I'm trying to write .vcf contact files that could incoporate an extension number. What works when dialing is putting a comma before the extension, as that puts a pause before dialing. However, when written in a .vcf, Android deletes the comma and the number doesn't dial anymore. Would anybody have any workarounds? thanks :)

writing the.vcf by hand (using comma)
dialing manually using comma (works)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.